# Get Self.cleaned_data without calling form.is_valid()

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a very basic question regarding django forms.
it is true that we can get 
    `self.cleaned_data`
after we call 
    `form.is_valid()`

but what if we want to get cleaned_data without calling is_valid?

anyway to call this ??

i need it because i have an advanced search form; i want user to enter as many cases as he wants.

i do not need the is_valid method because user can enter an empty form.

i need cleaned_data, i get 
    `IDs` in request.POST. i want to get values of them.

for example

```
`searchForm(forms.Form)
users = User.Object.all()`
```

i get user id in the POST, i want to get the value of it and send it to the HTML.

can anyone help me?

Comment: The documentation is quite explicit that cleaned_data doesn't exist until is_valid is called, and your justification for wanting it makes no sense at all.

Comment: i agree; it does not available. its just a question; to know if we can get it in anyother way. 
can you suggest what can be the answer of my question?

Answer (score 1):

Anything in `cleaned_data` is also in `request.POST`. You'll find your user id in there.